# How to install apt-get packages in an Azure Web App from GitHub YML

Tags: python, linux, azure-web-app-service, apt

I deployed a Web App from GitHub to an Azure Web App, running Python and Linux. My app needs ffmpeg to work, so I go to the SSH and run `apt-get install ffmpeg -y`, and everything works fine. The problem comes when my App is restarted or redeployed, since the files outside the home directory are not persistent in Azure App Services.

So, I tried to install the apt-get packages from the build, adding:

```
- name: Install packages
    run: sudo apt-get install ffmpeg -y
```

In the build section from the yml file under github/workflows. But when I go to my app, turns out the packages are not installed.

I also tried running the command in the deploy section, with the same results.

Comment: The [YML](https://fdik.org/yml/) is completely different from YAML (which it seems that you have). The [officially recommended extension](https://yaml.org/faq.html) for files containing YAML documents has been `.yaml` since at least September 2006.

Comment: As far as I understand, both .yml and .yaml are valid extension for a YAML file. The one I'm using was created automatically by linking Azure Web Apps to GitHub under the Deployment Center section, under .github/workflows. This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22268952/what-is-the-difference-between-yaml-and-yml-extension) talks about it.

Comment: Of course you can put a YAML document in file with any valid extension, e.g. `.json`, however what has been officially recommended for over 17 years now is `.yaml`, and IMO if you go against that recommendation, you either have to specify the reason why you do so. If Azure creates that automatically it probably has not been updated since the recommendation (or its programmers are a bit out of date).

Answer (score 0):

The Azure App Service SSH console is intended for diagnostic purposes, not for installing packages.

Try deploying your app with Docker. Docker allows you to create a container image that includes all the necessary components, including the packages you need.

This tutorial may be helpful for you: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/training/modules/deploy-run-container-app-service/

Comment: I'm not using containers since my PC says it doesn't have enough space to run Docker, therefore I deploy the app using the code option when creating my Azure Web App and pull the resources from GitHub since a YAML file is created automatically.

But if this is the only way to install apt-get packages from the build, I'll consider fixing that Docker issue. Thanks!